# React transfer event into onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have onClick event that excute fuction with several params. How to add to this paramt current event? I want to do in function somethig like this `event.stopPropagation()`

My code has the following view (all not nesseccary code was removed):

```
import React from 'react';

export default class AllCarWashTable extends React.Component{

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.removeCarWashHandler = this.removeCarWashHandler.bind(this);
    ...
};

removeCarWashHandler(e, name, id){
    e.stopPropagation();
    ...
}

generateRows() {
    const removeCarWashHandler = this.removeCarWashHandler
    ...

     return data.map(function(item) {
            var cells = cols.map(function(colData) {
             ... 
             <button type="button"  
                         onClick={()=> removeCarWashHandler(item['name'], item['id'])}>
                    ButtonName
              </button>
            ...
            });

}
}
```

Currenly my code leads to exception: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'stopPropagation' of undefined`
How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to pass the event to the function, it can be done giving the onClick event to the removeCarWashHandler function:

```
onClick={e => removeCarWashHandler(e, item['name'], item['id'])}
```

Comment: No worries, if the problem is solved you can mark my answer as right.